# How to import an image file and set it as a texture while in-game

Tags: godot, gdscript

Basically I want to import an image file and set it as a sprite/texture for an object while the game runs.

I just started coding so my code is a mess yet I will show you what I came up with.

I used a file dialog to select the file I wanted:

```
var selected = null

func _process(_delta):

if visible:

selected = get_current_path()
```

And then I tried to import the file I selected with load function and set it as a texture:

```
var tex = ImageTexture.new()
var img = Image

onready var imag = get_node("Sprite")
        
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_home"):
        img = load($FileDialog.selected)
        tex.create_from_image(img)
        imag.set_texture(tex)
```

But the thing is this only works for files within res:// folder. I can't import a file from a different directory which isn't already imported as a texture in godot editor. Help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Image.load(path)` to load an image from an arbitrary path. Make sure to check the returned error code.

```swift
var image_path = "..."

var image = Image.new()
var error = image.load(image_path)
if error != OK:
    # handle the error

var texture = ImageTexture.new()
texture.create_from_image(image)

sprite.texture = texture
```